# Using SQL for XML and Nested Table width

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xhtml, xquery

The code below will create a table, insert test data, and then format to send as html in email. The profile name needs to be set up in SQL, and the recipient needs to be edited to a valid email address. The resultant email looks as shown below.

```
create table #results ( docno varchar(50), customer varchar(250), telephone varchar(50),
    docamount money, operator varchar(250),  skuno varchar(50), descr varchar(500),
    quantity int, itemvalue money, batchlineno int, paymethod varchar(50))

insert into #results values ('ORDER1', 'Mickey Mouse', '12345678', 500, 'Joe Bloggs', 'ITEM-1', 'Item Description 1', 1, 300, 1, 'Credit Card')
insert into #results values ('ORDER1', 'Mickey Mouse', '12345678', 500, 'Joe Bloggs', 'ITEM-2', 'Item Description 1', 1, 200, 2, 'Credit Card')
insert into #results values ('ORDER2', 'Mary Poppins', '9008007', 300, 'Bob Marley', 'ITEM-1', 'Item Description 1', 1, 300, 1, 'Credit Card')



declare @body varchar(max) , @docno varchar(50) 
 select @body =   
  '<html>' +  
  '<head>'+  
  '<style> .inkclass {text-align: right;} </style>' +  
  '</head>'+  
  '<body>'+  
  '<h3>' + 'Report'  + '</h3>' 

if  exists(select * from #results)
begin
    declare cur cursor for select distinct docno from #results order by docno 
    open cur
    fetch cur into @docno
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        select @body +=   
          '<table border="5px" >' +  
          '<tr>'+  
          '<th>Doc. No.</th>'+
          '<th>Customer</th>'+
          '<th>Contact No.</th>'+
          '<th>Staff Member</th>'+
          '<th>Doc. Amount</th>'+
          '<th>Pay Method</th>'+
          '</tr>'  

        select @body = @Body +  cast(( select 
             convert(varchar(80), docno    ) as 'td','', 
             convert(varchar(80), customer    ) as 'td','', 
             convert(varchar(80), telephone     ) as 'td','', 
             convert(varchar(80), operator       ) as 'td','', 
             'text-align:right' as 'td/@style',convert(varchar(15), FORMAT(docamount  , 'N', 'en-us') ) as 'td','',
             convert(varchar(80),paymethod ) as 'td',''
             from #results    where batchlineno = 1 and docno = @docno             
            FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )

        select @body += ''

        select @body +=  '<table border="5px" >' +  
          '<tr>'+   
          '<th>Skuno</th>'+
          '<th>Description</th>'+
          '<th>Qty</th>'+
          '<th>Line Total</th>'+
          '</tr>'
        select @body = @Body +  cast(( select
             convert(varchar(80),skuno       ) as 'td','',
             convert(varchar(80),descr       ) as 'td','',
             'text-align:right' as 'td/@style',convert(varchar(15),FORMAT(quantity   , 'N', 'en-us')) as 'td','',
             'text-align:right' as 'td/@style',convert(varchar(15),FORMAT(itemvalue   , 'N', 'en-us')) as 'td',''
             from #results    where docno = @docno order by batchlineno
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 

        select @body += '</table></table><br><br>'

        fetch cur into @docno
    end
    close cur
    deallocate cur
end
select @body += '</body>' + '</html>' 


if exists(select * from #results)
begin
    exec msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MailProfileNameInSQL' ,
    @recipients = 'whomever@gmail.com' , @subject = 'Transaction Detail Report',
    @body = @body, @body_format = 'html' 
end

drop table #results
```

Output produced:

[output from sql above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKXb4.png)

Instead, I want to span the nested table columns to take up the full width of the parent table. This is probably easy enough to do in html, but how to do it with the sql for XML option? It should look like this (red arrow showing that the nested table columns should fill that area)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSmWo.png)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: It appears you might want the *outer* table to have a `colspan`, please show the rest of your code. SQL does not have any idea how to make XHTML, you need to tell it. Maybe create two [so] questions: What XHTML do you need to achieve your design? And how to get SQL Server to produce that?

Comment: I will post a full example later

Comment: Code and question has been expanded to a full example

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I will preface by saying that SQL Server is the wrong place to be constructing HTML. It only understands XML, so you would have to restrict yourself to XHTML to be compatible.

Ideally you should do this in some kind of scripting or client language, like C#, Python or Powershell. You can for example create a Powershell job in SQL Server Agent to be run on schedule.

---

Be that as it may:

- The attribute you need is `colspan="100"`.
- You want it on the *outer* table cell.
- You should probably just use `<div>` instead, but I haven't bothered with that.
- You don't need that horrible cursor code. You can just use `STRING_AGG` and some nested `CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML` to get the result you want.
- Note the way I create each row using `FOR XML`, then aggregate it using `STRING_AGG`. Had you just had a single big table then one `FPR XML` would have done the trick.

```sql
WITH innerTables AS (
    SELECT
      r.docno,
      r.customer,
      r.telephone,
      r.operator,
      r.paymethod,
      r.docamount,
      r.itemvalue,
      innerTable = 
          '<table border="5px" >' +  
          '<tr>'+   
          '<th>Skuno</th>'+
          '<th>Description</th>'+
          '<th>Qty</th>'+
          '<th>Line Total</th>'+
          '</tr>'+
          STRING_AGG(x.innerTable, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.batchlineno)+
          '</table></table><br/><br/>'
  
    FROM #results r
  
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          v.*
        FROM (VALUES
          (null, r.skuno),
          (null, r.descr),
          ('text-align:right', FORMAT(r.quantity, 'N', 'en-us')),
          ('text-align:right', FORMAT(r.itemvalue, 'N', 'en-us'))
        ) v([@style], [text()])           
        FOR XML PATH('td'), ROOT('tr')
    ) x(innerTable)
  
    GROUP BY
      r.docno,
      r.customer,
      r.telephone,
      r.operator,
      r.paymethod,
      r.docamount,
      r.itemvalue  
)
  
SELECT @body += STRING_AGG(
          '<table border="5px" >'+
          '<tr>'+
          '<th>Doc. No.</th>'+
          '<th>Customer</th>'+
          '<th>Contact No.</th>'+
          '<th>Staff Member</th>'+
          '<th>Doc. Amount</th>'+
          '<th>Pay Method</th>'+
          '</tr>'+
          x.outerTable+
          '<tr><td colspan="100">'+
          r.innerTable+
          '</td></tr>'+
          '</table></table><br/><br/>',
      '')
FROM innerTables r

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
      v.*
    FROM (VALUES
          (null, r.docno),
          (null, r.customer),
          (null, r.telephone),
          (null, r.operator),
          (null, r.paymethod),
          ('text-align:right', FORMAT(r.docamount, 'N', 'en-us')),
          ('text-align:right', FORMAT(r.itemvalue, 'N', 'en-us'))
    ) v([@style], [node()])
    FOR XML PATH('td'), ROOT('tr')
) x(outerTable);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aCPcHFGH)